# Apache Flink: How to apply patterns from a source onto another datastream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep

I've a datastream of events, and another datastream of patterns. The patterns are provided by users at runtime, and they need to come via a Kafka topic. I need to apply each of the pattern on the event stream using Flink-CEP.
Is there a way to get a PatternStream from the DataStream when I don't know the pattern beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible at this moment. FlinkCEP can handle only one Pattern applied statically. There is a JIRA ticket for that: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-7129 but can't tell the ETA for this feature.

Comment: Is it possible to replicate this logic using time windows?